# Java shutdown hook not running

Tags: java, shutdown-hook

I have a product service in Java. In our code I am creating shut down hook, but when I stop service it is not calling shut down hook consistently. Out of 5 stop calls it has called shutdown hook only once.

```
Runnable shutdownHandler = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        s_log.info("Shutting down thread..");
    }

};

Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(
        new Thread(shutdownHandler, "shutdownthread"));
```

Can anybody please tell me what could be the reason behind this not getting called consistently?

Comment: How is the process being shutdown? Depending on how it is killed, it might not get a chance to run the shutdown hook.  You should never assume it will be run as the process could be killed in such a way it can't be run.

Comment: Its a standard java process registered in windows. I am stopping service from service console of windows

Comment: What service runner are you using? Java doesn't have a built-in runner.

Comment: Maybe the logging service shuts down faster?

Comment: Do you have a proof that the hook doesn't run in those cases? Logging a message *is not a proof* since some logging frameworks ([e.g. Log4j2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400136/how-to-log-within-shutdown-hooks-with-log4j2)) have their own shutdown hooks and thus may be already shut down when you attempt to use the logging method.

Comment: Java doesn't have a standard way to be installed as a windows service. Are you using a tool or framework to do this?

Comment: We are using tomcat server to run our java application and that is registered as a windows service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Shutdown hook not run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404712/java-shutdown-hook-not-run)

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code:

```
Runnable shutdownHandler = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Shutting down thread..");
    }
};

Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(
        new Thread(shutdownHandler, "shutdownthread"));
```

and if it gives you expected output, you need to check the documentation of your logging framework.

Answer (score 0):

I am also finding that my framework (Jooby) and Java shutdown hooks work fine on my Mac on IntelliJ which sends a kill SIGINT (-2) however on Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS they don't run.

As my Java app is a webapp I came up with a simple workaround:

1. Setup a controller to listen to some url that isn't easily guessable e.g.

   ```
   /exit/fuuzfhuaBFDUWYEGLI823y82941u9y47t3u45
   ```
2. Have the controller simply do the following:

   ```
   System.exit(0)
   ```

Do a curl or wget from a script to the URL and the shutdown hooks all fire as JVM comes down.

I suspect for some reason on Linux there is a bug and no matter what interrupt that I use besides SIGKILL they all effectively behave like SIGKILL and the JVM comes down hard/abruptly.