# Execute JUnit inside a real forked VM using Maven

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

How to execute each method of a test inside a real forked VM? A real meaning the VM is really shutdown (and the shutdown hooks triggered) and the system properties are not shared between VM.

I use the following Maven surefire configuration.

```
<configuration>
     <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
     <parallel>methods</parallel>
     <threadCount>1</threadCount>
     <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
 </configuration>
```

And the following test.

```
public class ConcurrentIT {

    private static void test(String counter) throws InterruptedException {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(
            new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Checks if the shutdown hooks are triggered"))
        );
        System.out.println("PID is " + ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName()
            + " with the property before " + System.getProperty("toto"));
        System.setProperty("toto", counter);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1L);
        System.out.println("Counter is " + counter
            + " and the property value is " + System.getProperty("toto"));
    }

    @Test
    public void one() throws InterruptedException {
        test("1");
    }

    @Test
    public void two() throws InterruptedException {
        test("2");
    }


    @Test
    public void three() throws InterruptedException {
        test("3");
    }

    @Test
    public void four() throws InterruptedException {
        test("4");
    }
}
```

Expected output should looks like the following (and it works using the fork option of Intellij).

```
PID is 94969@Nicolass-MacBook-Pro.local with the property before null
Counter is 1 and the property value is 1
Checks if the shutdown hooks are triggered
PID is 94971@Nicolass-MacBook-Pro.local with the property before null
Counter is 2 and the property value is 2
Checks if the shutdown hooks are triggered
PID is 94972@Nicolass-MacBook-Pro.local with the property before null
Counter is 4 and the property value is 4
Checks if the shutdown hooks are triggered
PID is 94973@Nicolass-MacBook-Pro.local with the property before null
Counter is 3 and the property value is 3
Checks if the shutdown hooks are triggered
```

While the current out put is the following.

```
PID is 95773@Nicolass-MacBook-Pro.local with the property before null
Counter is 1 and the property value is 1
PID is 95773@Nicolass-MacBook-Pro.local with the property before 1
Counter is 2 and the property value is 2
PID is 95773@Nicolass-MacBook-Pro.local with the property before 2
Counter is 4 and the property value is 4
PID is 95773@Nicolass-MacBook-Pro.local with the property before 4
Counter is 3 and the property value is 3
```

Comment: You are aware of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34586597/1531124 ?

Comment: @GhostCat yes of course it only occurs if the process itself can execute the cleanup, I also tried different `shutdown` configurations (`exit` value that triggers a `System.exit(0)`)

Comment: As I know the default forkCount is 1, so there is no jvm fork in your example.

Comment: @SándorJuhos I tried with `<forkCount>2</forkCount>` and I got the same result

Comment: Are you sure about jvm fork is created, maybe the the first thread is run all the tests before the fork is created?

Comment: @SándorJuhos is there a way to check that?

Comment: You might check it in the log if run test from the command line with -X flag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170543/discussion-between-nicolas-henneaux-and-sandor-juhos).